# Why would my divs value be undefined?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating global `div` elements and assigning them all a value to represent their day of the week.

```
var daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
var daysOfWeekNum = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0]

var dayOfWeek = myDiv.append('div')
    .classed('dayOfWeek', true)

var dayLabels = daysOfWeek.forEach(function(DoW, DoWN){
   dayOfWeek.append('div')
        .attr("value", function(){ return parseInt((DoW == 'Sun') ? DoWN = 0 : DoWN = DoWN + 1)})
        .text(DoW)
})
```

Then later on down in the script, I run this.

```
d3.selectAll('div.dayOfWeek')
    .on('click', function(){
        console.log(this)
        console.log(this.value)
    })
```

So when I run `console.log(this)` the output looks like this:

`<div class = "dayOfWeek" value="4">Thurs</div>`

My problem is in the `console.log(this.value)`. I don't get a value when I try to log it. It just gives me `undefined`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can put a "value" attribute on a `<div>`, but you won't be able to see it as a property of the corresponding DOM element. It's not a standard property so it's not reflected in the DOM object model. You have to use `.getAttribute()` to see it.

Comment: Give the `div` an `id` (ex. `id="divIDExample"`) then try `document.getElementById('divIDExample').getAttribute('value')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divs don't have a `value` attribute in HTML, and the `value` property doesn't map on to the non-existent attribute in the DOM.

If you set the attribute, then you have to read the attribute to get the data base.

Since divs don't have a value attribute, you shouldn't be setting one though. Use `data-*` attributes if you want to add custom data to an element.

```js
document.querySelector('div').dataset.value = 1234;
alert(document.querySelector('div').dataset.value);
```

```html
<div>My div</div>
```